# Having difficulties using the QUERY option in "textract" start document analisys with boto3 python

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-textract

My problem is that textract asynchronous method start_document_analysis, has an option for the type of analysis you want to perform, but when I try to use the "Queries" feature =>

```
FeatureTypes=[
        'TABLES'|'FORMS'|'QUERIES',
    ],
```

you would have to pass another parameter with the queries list =>

```
QueriesConfig={
        'Queries': [
            {
                'Text': 'string',
                'Alias': 'string',
                'Pages': [
                    'string',
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
```

once I pass this parameter, boto3 throws an exception that Queries config is not recognized as one of the parameters accepted, have anyone used this feature with python before ?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution would be to use the `amazon-textract-textractor` package that wraps all this for you and helps you parse the responses. https://aws-samples.github.io/amazon-textract-textractor/index.html

For example this calls textract with the Queries, Forms and Tables API all at once:

```py
from textractor import Textractor
from textractor.data.constants import TextractFeatures
from textractcaller import QueriesConfig, Query

extractor = Textractor(profile_name="default")

document1 = extractor.start_document_analysis(    
    file_source='./multipage.pdf',    
    features=[TextractFeatures.QUERIES, TextractFeatures.FORMS, TextractFeatures.TABLES],
    s3_upload_path='s3://textractor-tests/debug/',
    s3_output_path='s3://textractor-tests/debug/',
    save_image=True,
    queries=QueriesConfig([Query("What is the first cell value")])
)
```

```
document1.queries[0].result
```

```
0.129853474
```

This calls the asynchronous API for you and will automatically block once you try to retrieve the value that the processing is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use by this way:

```
def getJobResults(jobId):

    pages = []
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.get_document_analysis(JobId=jobId)
    pages.append(response)
    print("Resultset page recieved: {}".format(len(pages)))
    nextToken = None
    if('NextToken' in response):
        nextToken = response['NextToken']
    while(nextToken):
        response = client.get_document_analysis(JobId=jobId, NextToken=nextToken)
        pages.append(response)
        print("Resultset page recieved: {}".format(len(pages)))
        nextToken = None
        if('NextToken' in response):
            nextToken = response['NextToken']
    return pages


def get_kv_map(s3BucketName, documentName):

    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.start_document_analysis(
        DocumentLocation={
            'S3Object': {
                'Bucket': s3BucketName,
                'Name': documentName
            }
        },
        FeatureTypes=['QUERIES'],
        QueriesConfig={
            'Queries': [
                {
                    "Text": "is 1. A. checkbox seleted"
                }
                
            ]
        }
    )
    
    job_id = response['JobId']
    response = client.get_document_analysis(JobId=job_id)
    status = response["JobStatus"]
    
    while(status == "IN_PROGRESS"):
        time.sleep(3)
        response = client.get_document_analysis(JobId=job_id)
        status = response["JobStatus"]
        print("Job status2: {}".format(status))
        
    response = getJobResults(job_id)    
    return response


def query_extraction():

    s3BucketName = "bucket-name"
    documentName = "xyz.pdf"

    data = get_kv_map(s3BucketName, documentName)
    
    return data

data = query_extraction()
```

Hope this will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
import trp.trp2 as t2 

def get_kv_map(s3BucketName, documentName):
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.start_document_analysis(
    DocumentLocation={
        'S3Object': {
            'Bucket': s3BucketName,
            'Name': documentName
        }
    },
    FeatureTypes=['QUERIES'],
    QueriesConfig={
        'Queries': [
            {
                "Text": "is 1. A. checkbox seleted"
            }
            
        ]
    }
)

    job_id = response['JobId']
    response = client.get_document_analysis(JobId=job_id)
    status = response["JobStatus"]

    while(status == "IN_PROGRESS"):
        time.sleep(3)
        response = client.get_document_analysis(JobId=job_id)
        status = response["JobStatus"]
        print("Job status: {}".format(status))
       
    return response



s3BucketName = "bucket-name"
documentName = "xyz.pdf"

data = get_kv_map(s3BucketName, documentName)
    
d = t2.TDocumentSchema().load(data)
page = d.pages[0]
query_answers = d.get_query_answers(page=page)
for x in query_answers:
    print(f"{x[1]},{x[2]}")
```

Comment: amazon-textract-response-parser library makes it easy to extract the answers to the questions from the Textract JSON schema

Answer (score 0):

The way to use start_document_analysis with queries is to specify ["QUERIES"] as featureTypes and also to provide the proper format for queries. This is an example:

```
import boto3
TEXTRACT = boto3.client('textract')

queries = {
      "Queries": [
        {
            "Text": "My dummy query 1?",
            "Pages": ["2"]
        },
        {
            "Text": "My dummy query 2?",
            "Pages": ["*"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }

# Send document to Textract for analysis.
response = TEXTRACT.start_document_analysis(
            DocumentLocation={
            'S3Object': {
                'Bucket': <my_bucket_name>,
                'Name': <my_source_file_path>,
            }
        },
        FeatureTypes=["QUERIES"],
        QueriesConfig=queries,
        NotificationChannel={
            'SNSTopicArn': <MY_TEXTRACT_TOPIC_ARN>,
            'RoleArn': <MY_TEXTRACT_ROLE_ARN>,
        }
```